# Is the Health App Graph Logarithmic?

Tags: health.app, graph

I'm looking at the Health App Graphs. The scale doesn't appear to be linear.

[image]

My question is: **Is the Health App Graph Logarithmic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look logarithmic to me.

Rounding the Steps figures, 20k peak, average 10k - the 10k line is half way up the scale, give or take.
If it were logarithmic it would be significantly off-centre.

I think it shows some non-colour-differentiated headroom above the high-point, which might be giving the impression it's not linear.

On my own phone, my high-point is about 3x my daily average. Allowing for that 'header' space above the high-point, my average line is showing as about ⅓ of the way up the scale; confirming my impression that it is linear, plus a header.